How do you compare DC battery voltage to voltage output from DC motor?
What is the difference and similarities with applying dc battery voltage and applying DC motor output voltage to a circuit or a DC motor with the same voltage (the same voltage we don't care about in this question) (using small dc motor applications)?

There is no difference. Constant voltage is constant voltage regardless of source. Can you elaborate why you need to ask if there is a difference or not, maybe you actually want to ask or understand something else? At least  based on your previous perpetual motion question.

Consider two identical DC motors connected via their shafts and apply (say) 12 volts to one motor (in order to turn it). Then measure the voltage generated by the 2nd motor (used as a generator). The voltage from the 2nd motor will be slightly less than 12 volts (maybe 11 volts). This is the fundamental problem but, I'll try and fill you in a bit more and relate this to your now closed question asked earlier today...
Because the 1st motor cannot ever be 100% efficient, it's equivalent to a series resistor (as the losses) and a 100% efficient motor. So, internally (across the 100% efficient motor) there might be only 11 volts (not 12 volts).
So, the output of the unloaded generator would be 11 volts and, if you tried to use that voltage to power the 1st motor, it wouldn't spin as fast and, this rapidly spirals down into both motors not spinning at all.
But, you are also expecting the generator (the 2nd motor) to produce current to feed the 1st motor (to overcome losses) and, that means there will be a volt-drop in that generator due to its own series resistive losses. Basically it boils down to trying to create perpetual motion and that doesn't work.

The main problem we don't understand is if battery voltage applied and dc motor voltage are the same OR different, is there a difference in sine wave or another road block? Even if the voltage from the 2nd motor was more, it still fails unless (this is just an idea)an attached circuit amplifier and maybe an installed rechargeable battery in that circuit to keep those motors working.

To conserve power with two motors connected mechanically with one as a generator, you cannot have losses and you can't generate more power out than what you put in @NoodleGooglles || Sure, you can use a motor powered by a battery and generate an output from an identical motor but the power output will not be sufficient to repower the motor. Losses are key; just like a clock must eat a little power to keep the pendulum swinging.

But you can use a battery to power a motor that turns a generator that powers a circuit but, the power output from the circuit will always be less than the power output from the battery. Power = volts x amps. Either you lose voltage or, you lose current or, you lose both. Nothing is 100% power efficient.

That was better for us to understand. Goodbye,  GOD BLESS YOU

@NoodleGooglles if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
